# Google Cloud TCP Load Balancer forward ip

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I use Google Cloud TCP load balancer forwarding requests to a Kubernetes NGINX service. As expected the logs on the NGINX show the Load Balancer IP. How can I retrieve the actual IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forwarded headers from the [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) are

```
X-Forwarded-For
X-Forwarded-Proto
```

Thus on nginx "$http_x_forwarded_for" shall be used

```
location / {
  ...
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  ...
}
```

If you are using Kubernetes and services you need to set the extrernal traffic policy to local

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: proxy-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: the-application
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: https
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$http_x_forwarded_for` variable to log the original ip of user.